# How to insert ID +1 and get last id?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert id and + 1 insert the form fields into a MySQL table. I want to get the last id for the insert operation as the return value of my query but I have some problems with it.

this is my code for get last id.

```
function GenIDInv()
{
    $CI = get_instance();
    $CI->db->select('n_id');
    $CI->db->from('sltax_notification_name');
    $CI->db->order_by("n_id", "desc");
    $query = $CI->db->get();
    $result = $query->row();

    if(!empty($result)){

        $result = $result->n_id;
        $rid = substr($result,6,9);
        $id =  $rid+1;
        echo date('Ym') . sprintf("%'.03d\n",$id);
    }
}
```

when i insert id it not +1

Comment: "Some problems" - You should be a little more descriptive about what that means.

Comment: when i insert id into database, id it not +1.

Comment: What does `+1` mean in your case?

Comment: i have id = 201812001, i want to get last id and insert id = 201812002 into data

Comment: I suspect you're not getting what you expect from $rid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i understood is that you want 201812001 to 201812002

Try this:

```
$rid = substr($result, 8, 1);
//echo $rid; // $rid should contains 1
$id =  $rid+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter documents: http://codeigniter.org.cn/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=max#CI_DB_query_builder::select_max

```
SELECT Max(n_id) FROM sltax_notification_name;
```

Comment: try is out :$result = $this->db->select_max('n_id')->from('sltax_notification_name')->get()->row();

Answer (score 0):

I make an assumption that your field `n_id` is compose like this : [YYYYMM][XXX] => [DATE][ID]

first question what happens if your id is greater than 999 ?

i will assumpt that you want to handle id greater than 999.

So now, the problem we need to resolve is how to add 1 to the id part, and keep it padded with 0 on the left.

You get your last id from database that's nice, it is probably a string.

The first thing we want to do is get the id part separate from date part.

```
$n_id = $result->n_id;
$id = substr($n_id, 6, strlen($n_id)) // we know the first 6 characters are part of the date and the rest is part of id
```

then we want to add one to `$id`

```
    $id += 1; // that statement will cast our string to int

    #Now we want to cast it to string and pad with 0 if needed 
    if (strlen($id) < 3) {
        $id = str_pad($id, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
```

Now, we just have to stick the piece together

```
   $date = new Datetime();
   $newN_id = $date->format('Ym').(string)$id
```